# how to run ROS program with eclipse

Tags: ros, node, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can compile the ros node in eclipse,but I don't know how to run the node,if anyone know how to do it ,please tell me ,thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223049/how-to-run-ros-program-with-eclipse/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this problem recently what I found was that in the run configuration you need to direct the eclipse to the binary. Check if you have the path to the binary and verify the binary is present in the place. it will be something like this

> /home/username/catkin_ws/devel/lib/package_name/executable_name

I also recommend you to follow this answer

http://answers.ros.org/question/52013/catkin-and-eclipse/

---

Originally posted by [ratmcu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25421/ratmcu/) with karma: 26 on 2015-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0